# Checking equality of 2 DOM Elements

Tags: javascript, dom

How may I check if 2 Dom element are same.

Form example

```
var element1 = document.getElementById("abc");
var element2 = document.getElementById("abc");
```

Now how should I chekc that these 2 elements are equal?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about reference equality of value equality? There may be two DOM elements on a page that are the same in sense that they have the same id, the same attributes and the same contents. Or, two different references (element1 and element2) may be referring to the same DOM node.

Answer (score -19, accepted):

---

***UPDATE***: This answer (the text below) was wrong despite being the accepted answer. Instead of comparing the IDs use an equality check of the elements: `element1 === element2`

---

<strike>If the Ids are the same, they cannot be different. If the Ids are different they cannot be the same. So if you have both Ids you can just compare the two Ids.</strike>

Comment: The `id` attribute of two elements __shouldn't__ be the same.  But people do weird things..

Comment: This is incorrect, any number of elements can have the same id, it is NOT guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: I was actually wrong. Tim you should better mark the bobobobo's answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 35):

`element1` and `element2` are references to the same place in the [DOM tree](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/dombasics).  Just check

```
if( element1 == element2 )
{
  alert("same") ;
}
```

Comment: Is this correct?  Will DOM elements always use the same Javascript object no matter how they are retrieved from the document?

Comment: Yes. Each element is an object in a tree, and `element1`, `element2` are merely references to those objects in the tree. If the two variables refer to the same object, then the references will be equal.

Comment: I know they are elements in a tree, I was more asking if the internals of `getElementById()` include something like `return new DomElement(...)` such that returned elements are always new instances, though they may contain the same info.  But I think you are right, browsers for the most part seem to reuse DOM JS objects.

Comment: `document.getElement*` definitely _does not_ clone the DOM object.  You would have to re-insert elements you change via these methods if it did!

Answer (score 6):

```
const equal = element1.isEqualNode(element2) // true
```

Comment: [Jordan Littell's answer](/a/33158336/5764553) already suggests using isEqualNode

Comment: @AndrewMyers I honestly didn't even see that. Some people are like me and just want to see the code rather than clicking on a link

Answer (score 5):

Check out the API for DOM nodes. It seems like you could use `isEqualNode` to achieve this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isEqualNode

Answer (score 0):

A possibility would be to use .outerHTML . It will generate the HTML of the element, including itself (not only the contents like .innerHTML).

Comment: This would seemingly not work for multiple, identical elements.